# Within a Callback validator for a Symfony sub-form collection, how do I get the value of a different field?

Tags: symfony, validation, collections, callback, subform

Let's say I have a Callback validator attached to a field in a collection sub-form that looks like this:

```php
$callback = new Callback([
    'callback' => function($obj, $context) {
        // Value of field to validate, no problem
        $value = $context->getValue();

        // Get the form, but gets my parent form
        $form = $context->getRoot();

        // Try and get other field value I need to validate current field,
        // but gets "child "otherfield" does not exist" error.
        $otherValue = $form->get('otherfield')->getData();

        // continue validation logic...
    }
]);
```

I need the value of another field from the specific form instance for the collection item, but I can't find a way to access the child form instance. How do I do this? I can access the list of forms for the collection by using the parent field that holds the collection, but I need the specific instance that this is validating.

It's Symfony version 3.3, but I can't find anything in a later version, either.

Comment: you should only access sub-elements of the element/data your validating. If your validator doesn't have access to a field, the validator is on the wrong property/level ...

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, that's what I'm doing. The field I need to access is on the same level as the field I'm validating. The issue is that I can't access any of the fields on the same sub-level, only the parent form. If you mean I shouldn't access any other fields in the form, only the value I'm validating, how do you suggest validating a field that depends on another field?

Comment: `$obj` should contain the object you're editing and sub-elements should just be. if obj is a *sibling* of whatever you're trying to access, you should put the callback on the parent.